# How to specify quotechar in R when writing csv?

Tags: r, export-to-csv

The `Python` library `Pandas` allows to specify a character used to quote fields in the DataFrame.to_csv function.

I'd like to use a similar function in `R` to use single quote instead of double quotes to quote non-numeric field. Is there a way to do so in `R` ?

I've tried the write.table and write.csv functions and I didn't found this option so I was wondering if there is a `R` package to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This writes out the first few rows of `iris` replacing each double quote with single quote:

```
writeLines(gsub('"', "'", capture.output(write.csv(head(iris), row.names =  FALSE))))
```

giving:

```
'Sepal.Length','Sepal.Width','Petal.Length','Petal.Width','Species'
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,'setosa'
4.9,3,1.4,0.2,'setosa'
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,'setosa'
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,'setosa'
5,3.6,1.4,0.2,'setosa'
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,'setosa'
```

As long as the data itself has no quotes it should be OK.